# Запрос к базе Oracle для получения N записей

Tags: sql, oracle

Как в SqlPlus написать запрос к таблице, который должен вернуть, скажем, 10 самых свежих по дате записей?

Comment: ORDER BY и такое вот https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1 вам в помощь

Comment: как всё просто, премного благодарен)

Comment: Конечно просто :-) Я с ораклом не работал ни разу, но гуглится все это на раз.